# Is there a free use library for group encryption?

Tags: encryption

I was wondering if there is a free encryption library that implements group encryption with multiple private keys and a single public key.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean for the single public key to be the signer.

OpenPGP can take care of that use case, and [the GNU Privacy Guard](http://www.gnupg.org/) (with its associated library) is a free implementation of OpenPGP.  I've used a Python binding to [gpgme](http://www.gnupg.org/related_software/gpgme/), myself.

(As I understand it, this is implemented by encrypting a symmetric key with each of the recipients' public keys, so that any of the recipients' private keys may be used to decrypt the message.)

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information. What I'm looking for does something like this:
a group manager key and a public key.
from there a group member can be added with their own private key.

Comment: Ah, OK.  Sorry, I have no idea.  You will want to edit that into your original question.  Let me know when you do this and I'll delete this answer, as it's not useful.